# Got issues when installing new components to react-native project

Tags: react-native, slider

Having issue in installing **react-native-slider**

I just tried this command

```
npm i --save react-native-slider
```

It shows following message.

> added 1 package and removed 29 packages in 1.944s

But it removed react packages

After that i am not able to run the project.

Comment: react-native which version.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do the following things**

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```